# Laravel 4.2- Redirect::back() issue

Tags: url, redirect, laravel-4

I have a project built on laravel 4.2. It used to work, but now it gives me  **`Cannot redirect to an empty URL.`** error, when I validate form.

As far as I know it comes from **Redirect::back()**. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: can you post your controller and routes code?

Comment: This error usually occurs when the URL you are trying to access do not exists. Check your URL again may be there is some mistake, 
In My Case I was trying to access the product url which I had already deleted from database...